# create pagination post meta_post

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am trying to make a pagination from meta_post (`meta_key`,`meta`_value) ==> (name_student,`array(john,mike,natasha,joan,buck)`) but i dont know how to make it, from [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) just make pagination post , not a meta_post , and my meta_post in 1 `array` , i was find a similar question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602397/set-post-per-page-using-get-post-meta) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564870/create-pagination-post-with-meta-post-image-value) , but I still haven't found the answer for my problem , if anyone can help me to find sollution for my problem I will be greatly helped , thankyou for read my problem , hopefully can help me

this my code :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $ids = get_the_ID();
    $args = array('paged' => $paged ,  'post__in' => array($ids));
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
 if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
     $metas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'name_student',false);
            foreach ($metas as $meta) {
                $key_val = explode(",", $meta);
                $image_chunk = array_chunk($key_val, 3);

                $page = get_query_var('page');
                $page = $page > 1 ? $page - 1 : 0 ;
                if (isset($key_val[$page])) {
                    foreach ($image_chunk[$page] as $image) {
                        echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>".
                        wp_get_attachment_image($image,"thumbnail") ."</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
   endwhile;
  $big = 9999;
  echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
   wp_reset_postdata();
   endif;
```

Comment: Please share the code you have so far, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: edited my code @cabrerahector